# Is there a way convert an elif and a while statment into one ?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, menu, structure

I'm am writing a simple program that look something like this:

```
while True:
    choice = float(input("options: "))

    if choice == 1:
        # Do something

    elif choice == 2:
        # Do something

    elif choice == 3: # <--- seems redudant
        while choice == 3:
            choice_return = input("do you want to return?: ")

                if choice_return == "yes":
                    choice = None
                else:
                   pass

     elif choice == 4:
         break
```

As noted in the the code, the "elif statment" seems redundant because it has the same conditions as the "while loop" below. You can of course simply write the code as follows:

```
while True:
    choice = float(input("options: "))

    if choice == 1:
        # Do something

    elif choice == 2:
        # Do something

    elif choice == 4:
        break

    while choice == 3: <--- three after four, no!!!
        choice_return = input("do you want to return?: ")     
             if choice_return == "yes":
                  choice = None
             else:
                 pass
```

which don't look to bad in this example, but in the actual code, it kinda ruins the structuring (and my OCD don't allow for that). Is there a way I can remove the redundancy while maintaining order?

NB. assume the "choice number" is fixed.

Comment: are there only 4 choices that a user can enter ?

Comment: you can use a switch case.

Comment: Python doesn't have a `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick to the `if/elif` structure and clean up things by wrapping the logic of `elif choice == 3` in a function and using a `while True` recipe in the function:

```
def myfunc()
    while True:
        choice_return = input("do you want to return?: ")
        if choice_return == "yes":
             return None # None here is redundant

while True:
    choice = float(input("options: "))

    if choice == 1:
         ...

    elif choice == 3:
         choice = myfunc()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `choice` as the condition in the `while` loop. Restructure it so it uses `break` to stop the loop when appropriate.

```
elif choice == 3: # <--- seems redudant
    while True:
        choice_return = input("do you want to return?: ")
        if choice_return == "yes":
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the inner while loop into a function, the code will then be much cleaner.  You will still have both tests, but integer comparisons are fast - so why are you using `float`?

Better yet, if you could but every "case" into a function you could use a list of functions.

```
# Functions return True to break out of the loop, otherwise False

def case1():
    # Do something

def case2():
    # Do something

def case3():
    # Do something

def case4():
    # Do something

cases = [case1, case2, case3, case4]

while True:
    choice = int(input("options: "))

    if choice < len(cases) and choice >= 0:
        if cases[choice]():
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid option", choice)
```